# how to depense repaly attack using jwt

Tags: security, networking, spring-security, jwt

JWT is used as user authentication in my project.
If someone intercepts packets(using wireshark, etc), takes the user's jwt token, and then tries to log request in using the jwt token(replay attack)
how can i defend using jwt? (my project is using https)

ps. English is not my native language, so I am not good at it, so please understand the awkward sentences.

Comment: My mistake, I used the ambiguous expression "using jwt". I want to defend against attacks while adhering to jwt authentication.

Answer (score 1):

A JWT literally IS your access token. So you have to keep it secure and especially transfer it securely by all means. If an attacker was able to obtain a JWT (for example by sniffing an unencrypted HTTP connection) he can always* use it to perform **any** action the user (respectively the token) is authorized to. So it's more of a use than a "replay attack".

Therefore you cannot directly defend using a JWT. You can only make sure to send it always over an encrypted HTTPS connection and to prevent Cross-Site-Scripting attacks, which could allow an attacker to steal the JWT.

* Because of this, a JWT generally has an expiration time. So if you keep the expiration time short an attacker could use the stolen JWT only in a small time period. However, also a small time period may be sufficient to achieve permanent access. And the attacker could possibly steal a fresh JWT via the initial source.

Comment: first thanks for your kindness @Cryptkeeper
I have two questions
1. Even if the expiry time of jwt is set short if it is possible for an attacker to re-acquire and attack within that time, how short should the expiry time be?
2. Can't i just defend the hijacked jwt token from being used meaningfully on the server side and in login logic?

Comment: 1. I don't think there is a general valid rule. It depends strongly on your application and architecture. If it's shorter you need a mechanism to automatically refresh the token. Or you can make it longer and require the user to manually log in again if it's expired. Take a look at OAuth or Keycloak to get an idea how tokens are generally managed.

Comment: 2. No, you can't. As long as the token is not expired you have no possibility to distinguish whether the request is legitimately coming from the user or the attacker. If you noticed an attack you could probbably blacklist the whole token on the server side. But there is no generally way to invalidate a token as long it's not expired.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment. @Cryptkeepr
I have a one question
1. Even if an attacker can make a login request, Is there a way to prevent logging in?